# How can I get a soft return?

Tags: output-formatting

I want to have two different type of newline so I can print a string which looks like it has multiple newlines but gives me a way to differentiate between them. I want to have string with newlines in them and look them up using `RegularExpresssion["...\n...\r..."]->...`. Basically there will be a huge string with mix of hard and short returns then I will have a bunch of `StringReplace[...]` where `\n` will be captured and replace by something and `\r` by something else.

- Is there a way to have hard and soft returns in a Mathematica string?
- If I should write a string like `"sdfsdf\nadsad\rasdasd"`, is there a function, say `StringPrint["sdfsdf\nadsad\rasdasd"]`, which will convert the `"\n"` and `"\r"` to their print form? Note: For this I want to do inline evaluation by first selecting and pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` not `Shift+Enter` evaluation.

`Enter` is the keybinding for `\[Newline]` which is `\n` but since `Shift+Enter` is reserved for evaluation while it is a standard key for soft return `\r`. If `\[Newline]` equivalent for `\r` can be found that would still make the life easier as well.

Comment: I don't really understand. Simply `Print`ing a string (or returning it from an evaluation) with line ending characters will show those characters as line breaks.

Comment: I think I found it `\:000a` is the hex way to enter `\n` and `\:000d` is the hex way to enter `\r` and I think hex way might be the only way to input in print form `\r`. `\n` already has a key binding `Enter` and various aliases like `\[Newline]`, `\[RawReturn]`, `\[ParagraphSeparator]` etc , does `\r` also has some hidden keybinding or aliases?

Comment: Oh, wait. I think I get it. Can't you just escape the backslash? I.e., `StringReplace[str, {"\r" -> "\\r", "\n"-> "\\n"}]`